# Java images loaded in ide but not built jar

Tags: java, image, build, jar, embedded-resource

I have my file path as follows:

```
  +------------+           +-----------------+      +------------------+
  |            |           |                 |      |                  |
  | src        +----------->  com            +--+--->  application     |
  |            |           |                 |  |   |                  |
  +------------+           +-----------------+  |   +------------------+
                                                |
                                                |   +------------------+
                                                |   |                  |
                                                +--->  resources       |
                                                    |                  |
                                                    +------------------+
```

My code is in the application folder and my pictures that I want to load are in resources.

Im using the following code to get the images from resources onto a class in application (image is a BufferedImage).

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File("./src/com/resources/Pad.png"));
```

This seems to work in my IDE (intellij) as I can see the loaded images as *[shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC4ie.png)*

However, when I build, the images aren't being shown. I'm building by:

File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> Green plus -> JAR -> From modules with dependencies -> my main class location -> Extract to target Jar

Then I Build Artifact -> Build.

So when I go to the destination of the built jar and run it none of the pictures are being [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZwnq.png)

I checked to see if the images were in the built jar by extracting the jar which does contain the pictures but for some reason the code isn't loading the picture.

Comment: Please clarify package of `ImageIO` class. Is it `javax.imageio`?

Comment: it is `import javax.imageio.ImageIO;`

Comment: Never, ever reference `src` in your code - for just the reasons you are now having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use resourse as a stream instead of file.

```
image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/resources/Pad.png"))
```

Comment: This has solved it thanks. the stream seems to make it work, do you know why it works as a stream but not when I use a File?

Comment: @NotSoVisualBasic Do you understand what a Jar file is?  It's just a Zip based file.  So when you "Jar" your project, all the files are stored inside a single binary file, this means the "files" can no longer be accessed via the file system (because they don't exist), instead, you need to make use of the API to find and load those resources which are embedded in the Jar file (or, as a neat side affect here, within the class path)

Comment: Yeah I understood that a jar file was like a zipped folder but I didn't realise after building you wouldn't be able to access the files like you would if the program was being developed in an IDE. Thanks for the explanation though!

Answer (score 0):

The src path is not available in build jar. You should use class loader to load resources from classpath. E.g. (assuming that 'src' is classpath root)

```
image = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass()                   
.getResource("com/resources/Pad.png").getPath());
```

**Edited** with the @MadProgrammer suggestion.

Comment: This didn't work for me I used: `image = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/resources/Pad.png").getPath()));` since File wouldn't use URL, and the built jar doesnt have the pics shown.

Comment: The question is: What is your claspath root?

Comment: I don't know, how would I find it?

Comment: using `image = ImageIO.read(new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/resources/Pad.png").getPath()));` I can see the images when i run the program from the IDE but if i build it, the images aren't being loaded when i run the jar.

Comment: `new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader()                     
.getResource("com/resources/Pad.png")` is defunct and pointless.  A resource embedded within a `Jar` file will not be accessible as a `File`, that's the whole point of using `Class#getResource`.  Also, since `ImageIO.read` doesn't take a `String` you're just generating a compiler error - Simple use `this.getClass().getResource("...")` instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer you right. And it, eventually, use getClassLoader() as well. Excerpt from doc. _"Otherwise, if this class is not in a named module then the rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class."_. I'll fixed the answer.